# Datatables: how to get column's sum with an unknown column ordinal number

Tags: datatables

In my project I have a very wide table. In which each user define and hide some columns on his own. Column order preferences are stored on the server and are unknown at client side.

My task to calculate the sum of certain columns and display it in the table footer. I can calculate sum in the classical way and use it in other tables where the order of the columns is known.

But what about this case? For the user Paul, the "price" column can have a order number 8, and for the user John - 12. At the same time, Paul and John can change the order of these columns at any time in their interface.

May be possible that instead of

```
table.column(14).data().sum();
```

I can make this:

```
  table.column("mnemonic_name").data().sum();
```

?

I could not find an answer in the Datable forum and here. Please help. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign names to your columns, in the DataTable definition.

For example:

```
columns: [
 title: "ID", name: "identifier", data: "id" },
 title: "Quantity", name: "quant", data: "quantity" }
]
```

Then you can use a column selector based on the assigned names, instead of the indexes:

```
table.column( 'quant:name' ).data();
```

You can see the column-selector documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector#%7Bstring%7D:name) for further details.

Comment: Thank you, I have not seen this method earlier.
I pressed the plus sign for You, but the system replied that I am defective and therefore it would not be credited :(

Comment: No problem! Thank you for accepting my answer. You can take the [tour] and read about how [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) work. Once you have earned enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to vote.